# Qt 4.7 visual touch/click feedback

Tags: c++, qt, touch

I have a complex application in Qt and I want to add visual feedback of touch or mouse press/release. What is the best approach to do this? I have some ideas how it can be implemented, but every idea has some problems. Target application will run under QWS but I would like to implement it and test it under X11 first.

**Custom paint event**

- reimplement paint event of all frames or derivate all frames from some subclass
- my application is so complex to implement this

**"Glass frame" over application**

- one frame is transparent and captures all mouse events
- frame is always on top and displays animation of touch
- I don't know how to propagate events from this "glass frame" to underlying components and how to determine current active frame

**Special cursor**

- use special animated cursor image
- display cursor on press and hide cursor on release
- I don't know how to animate graphics of that cursor

**Existing component/mechanism**

- it is possible, that there is some existing mechanism for that, but I didn't find anything